# Tune a pre-existing model with Keras Tuner

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-tuner

I am looking at [Keras Tuner](https://keras-team.github.io/keras-tuner/) as a way of doing hyperparameter optimization, but all of the examples I have seen show an entirely fresh model being defined. For example, from the Keras Tuner [Hello World](https://keras-team.github.io/keras-tuner/examples/helloworld/):

```
def build_model(hp):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)))
    for i in range(hp.Int('num_layers', 2, 20)):
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=hp.Int('units_' + str(i), 32, 512, 32),
                               activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(
            hp.Choice('learning_rate', [1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])),
        loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

I already have a model that I would like to tune, but does that mean I have to rewrite it with the hyperparameters spliced in to the body, as above, or can I simply pass the hyperameters in to the model at the top? For example like this:

```
def build_model(hp):
    model = MyExistingModel(
        batch_size=hp['batch_size'],
        seq_len=hp['seq_len'],
        rnn_hidden_units=hp['hidden_units'],
        rnn_type='gru',
        num_rnn_layers=hp['num_rnn_layers']
    )
    optimizer = optimizer_factory['adam'](
        learning_rate=hp['learning_rate'],
        momentum=0.9,
    )
    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer,
        loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'],
    )
    return model
```

The above *seems* to work, as far as I can see. The model initialization args are all passed to the internal TF layers, through a `HyperParameters` instance, and accessed from there... although I'm not really sure *how* to pass it in... I *think* it can be done by predefining a `HyperParameters` object and passing it in to the tuner, so it then gets passed in to `build_model`:

```
hp = HyperParameters()
hp.Choice('learning_rate', [1e-1, 1e-3])

tuner = RandomSearch(
    build_model,
    max_trials=5,
    hyperparameters=hp,
    tune_new_entries=False,
    objective='val_accuracy')
```

Internally my model has two RNNs (LSTM or GRU) and an MLP. But I have yet to come across a Keras Tuner `build_model` that takes an existing model like this a simply passes in the hyperparameters. The model is quite complex, and I would like to avoid having to redefine it (as well as avoiding code duplication).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed this *is* possible, as [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/issues/407) makes clear...

However rather than passing the `hp` object through the `hyperparameters` arg to the Tuner, instead I override the Tuner `run_trial` method in the manner suggested [here](https://keras-team.github.io/keras-tuner/tutorials/subclass-tuner/#adding-hyperparameters-during-preprocessing-evaluation-etc).